# Spine. What is the name of the process?

Tags: 3d, animation, polygon

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twUz99ek5do&list=WL&index=5

There is a process from 1:51, where the guy start making polygons around the bodyparts. I think this is this part is where (with later transformations) you can make a single draw like a 3D animation (with transforming the triangles). What is the name of the process, and is this effect available in other animation softver? 
I'm thinking about mostly maya, spriter or unity.
Ty

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be simply [skeletal animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation), which is a standard technique that is available in all modern animation packages. Whether applied to 3D meshes or (as here) 2D ones, the principle is the same.

The pseudo-3D effect on the sprites is created by using a mesh where vertices are placed along the contours of the sprite texture, then animated to squash and stretch parts the image in such a way that it creates the illusion of 3D motion, even though the sprite images are authored in 2D. There's [a description of the technique in the Spine docs](http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-meshes#Deformation).